# Bluetooth data to HID for BLED112

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth

We have bought BLED112 to interface our target via BT.
An android app interacting with target via BT & USB (HID).
We have used some Bluetooth communication to write a program and send data to dongle.
Now can somebody here having any experince in converting that BT data to a HID signal.
Have anybody tried that?
Is there any BGScript code which we need to write to achieve that?

Please let me know if the thought is completely wrong.

Comment: Did you mean that your BLED112 should speak with your Android app over BLE interface? FWIK, BLED112 is a BLE-based USB dongle, and not a module.

Comment: *"We have used some Bluetooth communication to write a program and send data to dongle"*. I don't quite comprehend this.

Comment: BGScript script is (usually) dumped into the BLE module and not in BLED112

Comment: Many thanks for the reply WedaPashi.Yes we are writing an Android App which can send data to BLED112 over BLE interface or GATT. My question is how can I convert that data (basically a command) to an HID (key event), correct me if my understanding is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to a comment above which states,

> We are writing an Android App which can send data to BLED112 over BLE interface or GATT. My question is how can I convert that data (basically a command) to an HID (key event), correct me if my understanding is wrong?

If I understand the use-case correctly, I think, in the initial stages of the development, you will need to use the BLE-GUI utility that BlueGiga provides.

With that utility you can see the communication between the BLED112 Dongle and the BLE112 Module. BLED112 shall be simulating what the android app would do?

First, you will need to know the GATT structure stored in BLED112 to write to or read from the BLED112. 
Secondly, the way BLE112 works is an event-based implementation. Going through the API reference document for BLE112 shall help you understand the events generation conditions and codes that are generated modified when a characteristic value is updated by the android application, or read by android application. You get events for connection, disconnection, read from, write to, notification enabled for, indication enabled for, etc.

On the BLE112 side, depending upon what service and what characteristics in that service is going to be used for data transfer between Client (Android App) and Server (BLE112), you need to write suitable implementation in event callback handlers.

There is a standard service called Human Interface Device which has a reserved UUID: 0x1812.

Once you configure your BLE112 as a HID over GATT device, your android app shall see a service with UUID: 0x1812. Parse the service descriptor and get the characteristics bundled up into the service. You can read from or write to that service depending upon access parameters set in gatt.xml

As an example, say, if it is a Keyboard, you can send the scancode for (make and break) of the key depending upon what key is pressed. How to get a scancode is out of the scope of this question anyway, and sadly I had worked on PS2 keyboards, so I don't really know how to get the scancode from a USB keyboard.

So, you have the scancode for the key pressed, and you know the characteristics to write that into. Write it, the application should enable the Notifications for that characteristics, so that it is notified whenever the key is pressed and value is written into the characteristics. To let application enable notifications or indications for the characteristics, study the developer guide that talks about how to write a gatt.xml for Bluegiga-based BLE devices. I'll give you a hint: in xml, in the characteristics configuration you have to write notify="true".

About parsing of the service and characteristics in Android, Unfortunately I am not an android developer, but an embedded developer, I know how the BLE112 module part is to be implemented, while I have no insight of how android parses the data. But, there are plenty of question and discussions about it online, which you might understand better than me since you have an android background.

Comment: ,Many thanks for the detailed explanation, yes you are perfectly right, I'm eagerly waiting to get my BLE112 which is expected tomorrow, I've already installed the BLE1.3.2 SDK downloaded from Bluegiga, I shall check this service mentioned above and keep you posted how it goes...

Comment: Have got one more query on this topic," you need to write suitable implementation in event callback handler" does this mean like all the keyboard events can be mapped to my own look up table.?? And also can you be more specific on this point please "Parse the service descriptor and get the characteristics bundled up into the service. You can read from or write to that service depending upon access parameters set in gatt.xml" because I might need around 15-18 button processed in my Android app as HID events.Am I missing something here?

Comment: We have got this BLED112 firmware updated to 1.3.2 build and have connected to our target (Linux OS), and surprisingly it is not detecting as a HID device, from the manual it is mentioned that only it is available as CDC, does that mean that BLED112 alone is not enough for this activity? Slightly confused

Comment: Flash your BLE112 module with HID firmware, you are not supposed to flash BLED112 (Dongle). BLED112 is CDC as expected.

Comment: We didn't buy this BLE112, one of the site where we bought mentioned wrongly that HID is supported on BLED112, BLE112 looks like a CHIP, should we need to buy the whole development kit, CC debugger...so on for flashing firmware....that actually doesn't solve our purpose,we thought BLED112 would give the HID events straight, Is there any option left for us with BLED112 (Serial port data to HID conversion)?

Comment: There is a lot of ambiguity now, so ask a separate question. SO community tends to flush out the long communication through comments, which makes sense.

Comment: You can try BleuIO. similar device but advance feature. https://bleuio.com